# Arrayformula with SUMIFS does not dropdown

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to solve this problem for a while already. I have read some questions here, but none of them solved my problem.

I have a table with some stock data and I am trying to calculate the average price until that moment using an ARRAYFORMULA, what I want is in ColH, but my ARRAYFORMULA does not dropdown automatically and honestly I can't understand the reason for it.

[PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEomt.jpg)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sRDNCyWK1LItqETYoWSOV9eiEI4mySDetlBcbupwbvk/edit?usp=sharing

The formula I am using is:
`=ArrayFormula(SUM(FILTER($G$2:G2;$C$2:C2="Buy";$D$2:D2=INDEX($D2:$D;1);$A$2:A2=INDEX($A2:$A;1)))/SUM(FILTER($E$2:E2;$C$2:C2="Buy";$D$2:D2=INDEX($D2:$D;1);$A$2:A2=INDEX($A2:$A;1))))`

Why this is not working? I have tried with SUMIFS as well but it did not work.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: @player0 I updated with a link to my sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(
 INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(IF(C2:C="buy"; ROW(C2:C))))=IF(ROW(
 INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(IF(C2:C="buy"; ROW(C2:C)))))>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(IF(C2:C="buy"; ROW(C2:C)))))); TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(IF(C2:C="buy"; ROW(C2:C))))); ); ROW(
 INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(IF(C2:C="buy"; ROW(C2:C)))))&"×"&
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&MAX(IF(C2:C="buy"; ROW(C2:C))))&"×"&
 INDIRECT("E2:E"&MAX(IF(C2:C="buy"; ROW(C2:C)))); )); "×"); 
 "select sum(Col2)/sum(Col3) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)/sum(Col3)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! Amazing! I did not know about FLATTEN, good to know about it. It took me a while to understand your formula and I am not sure if I understood fully, but great that it worked. Thank you very much.